# Actionscript 3.0 - Tween a Movie Clip randomly and change it's font family over time

Tags: actionscript-3, tween, flash-cs5.5

I have a Movie Clip which consists of a text-box with some text in it.

I am trying to tween this movie clip so it either moves randomly throughout the animation or have the movie clip bounce off the edges similar to a standard screen saver you might see. While slowly changing it's text through many different font families

Is it possible to have a movie clip tween randomly through an animation and is it possible to change the text to many different families in a slow transition.

I hope that makes sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7e0a.html) for some pointers on scripting animation. Since you want to apply this to a `MovieClip` (in the Flash IDE I take it?), you'll have to make your class extend `MovieClip` and assign it to the movie clip in the library.

Bouncing it off the edge etc. are behaviors you'll have to code yourself. I'd recommend having a current movement vector, like

```
private var movement:Point;
```

Initialize it to a random direction and value:

```
movement = new Point(Math.random(), Math.random());
movement.normalize(INITIAL_VELOCITY);
```

And each frame, adding it to the movie clip's current position:

```
public function update():void {
    x += movement.x;
    y ++ movement.y;
    doBounce();
}
```

Bounce:

```
public function doBounce():void {
    // something like:
    if (x + width + MARGIN) >= stage.width) movement.x *= -1; // bounce off right side
    if (x + MARGIN <= 0) movement.x *= -1; // bounce off left side
    // similar for y and height
}
```

This is untested code, but should get you started.

On the topic of transitioning between fonts: It depends on the transition you want. You could fade 1 `TextField` out (reducing its `alpha` property to 0 over time) while fading a second one in, with a different font. If you want to morph between font shapes - I don't think that's possible with dynamic text, because I don't think you can "render" font outlines/glyphs to `Graphics` in the API, but not 100% sure.